# Can a freelancer doing business as a natural person travel to the US to meet a client on a B1/B2 visa?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, business-travel, freelance

Web Designer.

Designing websites as a natural person (does not own a business).

Travels to the USA on a B1/B2 visa to meet a client.

Meets the client to get to know them and their business.

Takes pictures of their headquarters and production premises. (the images could possibly be used on the website)

Travels back to their home country to produce the website.

The client pays the freelancer directly since he/she does not own a business. The freelancer is paid while he/she is outside of the US, either before the visit or after the visit.

---

Is this possible on a B1/B2 visa?

Comment: I'm confused.  If you don't own your own business, are you actually working for anyone? Or is this US company paying you directly?

Comment: @PeterM I mean that I don't own a company, I'm a freelancer working for myself. I do a website for a client, and that client pays me directly for that website.

Comment: Googling for "Matter of Hira" will find you a number of interesting readings...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you can. A B1/B2 allows you to fully participate in business meetings, you may conduct negotiations, and you may discuss planned investments or purchases. Which seems to more than cover "meeting and getting to know the customers".

Although I'm from a country participating in the B1/B2 visa waiver program, I've never had any problem visiting our branch offices in the USA to participate in meetings.

http://workpermit.com/immigration/usa/us-b-1-business-visitor-visa-and-b-2-visitor-pleasure-visa

Comment: when you travel for meetings... How does it go with the airport's immigration officer? You simply say it's for business and that you are attending a meeting? They don't ask anything else? or do they ask many questions after you say that?